# outlook.js onSend support for Office 2016/2019 (not connected to 365)

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows) for onSend support in office add-ins states:

> The on send feature is currently supported for Outlook on the web in
>   Office 365 (in preview), Exchange 2016 on-premises (Cumulative Update
>   6 or later), and Exchange 2019 on-premises (Cumulative Update 1 or
>   later). This feature is also available in preview on Windows and Mac
>   connected to an Office 365 subscription. Add-ins that use the on send
>   feature aren't allowed in AppSource.

I'm wondering if the onSend feature will support the following configuration:
Office 2016/2019 (not connected to 365) with Exchange 2016 on-premises.
Office 2016/2019 (not connected to 365) with Exchange via 365

Comment: Answering your question in sections,

1.Office 2016/2019 (not connected to 365) with Exchange 2016 on-premises Yes, provided you are on CU 6 and later

2.Office 2016/2019 (not connected to 365) with Exchange via 365 Are you referring to exchange Online? (which is the non on-prem case). Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Regarding my second configuration: "Office 2016/2019 (not connected to 365) with Exchange via 365" I mean an email account that uses "https://outlook.office365.com" as its exchange server.  I'm not sure if that is "exchange online" or not?  Your answer that Office 2016/2019+Exchange 2016 on-prem being supported is different than the answer I received here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-dev-docs/issues/651#issuecomment-541733658.  Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Availability of onSend on different platforms]

Please find the image explaining availability of onSend on different platforms